# refresh Spring bean instance property periodically best practice?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, concurrency

I have a spring component that calls AWS to do some stuff. It acquires temporary session credentials lasting for <=1h to initialize the AWS service client at the start of my app. The AWS service client is set as an instance property of the bean. Then after this hour, I need to block all threads using this bean and refresh the temporary session credentials used by the service client.

Is there any recommended way to do this? Any hints/clues are appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think that it would be best (and easiest) for you to implement it as a sort of a proxy.

First, create a class for an object that will be refresh. Lets call it `RefreshableProperty`.

Then you need the proxy which will have following responsibilities:

- It will be injected into any place that requires access to `RefreshableProperty`
- It would have an instance of a field of type `AtomicReference<RefreshableProperty>`
- It can have a method annotated with `@Scheduled` (with some cron expression) that would be invoked periodically
- This method would connect to your configuration server and download new settings which would be put into a new instance of `RefreshableProperty`
- At the end of such operation your code should swap the reference so that it points to a new object

If you need to have it being done exactly every hour then it will be a difficult task and I would strongly advise against it since it would be very tricky to synchronize this service client with your Spring Application.

Comment: I like your idea. Let me get it straight. So in my AWS caller component, I will have AtomicReference<AWSserviceClientWrapper> myAwsClient = AtomicReference<AWSserviceClientWrapper>  And a method in my AWS caller component is annotated with @Scheduled of desired periods to update "myAwsClient" every once a while

Comment: Yes. Assuming the timer on which you want to update is not extremaly strict.

Comment: many thanks for your kind help. I tried it and it worked. I used AtomicReference to wrap my AWS client, and a @Scheduled method to create a new AWS client with refreshed credentials, at the end of the method, atomicReference set. Don't have multithreaded test, but according to the javadoc of atomic package, the get and set method of atomic is like having volatile variable so there should be no race condition